# Adding www-data to /etc/sudoers dos not work for PHP shell_exec() to run a command

Tags: sudo

I'm running the webserver lighttpd on Raspbian (Debian based) on a Raspberry Pi. The server runs as user www-data (checked with `ps aux`). I added the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
```

to be able to run the `vcgencmd` tool from the Raspberry Pi that gives status information from within a PHP file with

```
<? echo shell_exec('vcgencmd version'); ?>
```

All it prints is "VCHI initialization failed" (instead of the supposed version information that appears when I run it on my user even without `sudo`) which appears when vcgencmd is run with wrong permissions.

Running for example

```
<? echo shell_exec('cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp'); ?>
```

works fine without any `/etc/sudoers` change, so there's no problem with PHP (like forbidden `shell_exec` or something).

What else needs to be set in order to execute a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use something you added to `/etc/sudoers`, you have to call `sudo`.

`sudo` is just a program with the setuid bit set. There's absolutely nothing more special about it, meaning it doesn't interpose itself every time a program is launched.

The reason you can call `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` is because you have read access to those files. Depending on how your filesystem permissions are set, you may have read access, but not necessarily write.

The reason `vcgencmd version` might work when launched as your own user has 2 possible explanations:

1. You have `alias vcgencmd='sudo vcgencmd` in your profile, thus you automatically run `sudo`.
2. You have sufficient permissions to the files that `vcgencmd` needs to operate. If you need write access, and the files are owned by a group you're a member in, and have write access for that group, then you won't need sudo.

---

In summary, either change your command to `sudo vcgencmd version`. Or find what file permissions you need to modify and modify them.